# Eclipse obsolete methods on the stack

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm using Eclipse for Java on my Macbook air, OS 10.9. I keep getting the error `Obsolete Methods on the Stack`, with a warning about how it may cause problems with the virtual machine when I run very basic programs that have no errors. I ran a program that just had the class and the main method and I got this error. After the error box, the bug referred to the main method, but I know the syntax is correct because I used Eclipse's main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dowhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(value);*/
        /*do{
            System.out.println("Enter a number ");
            int value = scanner.nextInt();

        }
        while(value != 5);
        System.out.println("Got 5");*/
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I'm not getting the obsolete methods error now, just `Exception in thread "main"... at line 5`.

Comment: You are editing the program while debugging, and Eclipse is telling you that it has trouble keeping your source code and the running program in sync. So don't do that. And it's just a warning, not an error or bug in your program.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't see why I am editing the program while debugging, I wasn't doing anything after I ran it. And it did say there was an error in the code, in the line with the main method.

Comment: 1. Please post your code, even if you're sure it has no errors. 2. Are you sure your program has terminated? (No red "stop" button on the eclipse toolbar)

Comment: I started a new program in Eclipse and it is working fine. I don't know what the problem was with the previous one. It kept having the bug in main method, compilation error. It may have had something to do with file management. One thing that was different was that I did not have the Package Explorer view, and now I do.

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that you are doing hot code replace, and that
the frames on the stack no longer match the class files in the running VM.
Restarting your debug session/target VM should suffice.

Hot code replace (HCR) meaning:

It is a debugging technique whereby the Eclipse Java debugger transmits new class files over the debugging channel to another JVM.

[read more](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/57630/).

[Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=95334)

[Dreamincode](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/175892-obsolete-methods-on-the-stack-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on Terminate button and it no longer showed that warning message again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31014777)